# Testing after_create with rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have code in my model.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :create_node_for_foo

   def create_node_for_user
     FooBar.create(id: self.id)
   end
end
```

and have code in rspec of Foo model

```
describe Foo do

  let (:foo) {FactoryGirl.create(:foo)}

  subject { foo }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:fullname) }

 it "have mass assignable attributes" do
  foo.should allow_mass_assignment_of :email
  foo.should allow_mass_assignment_of :fullname
 end

 it "create node in graph database" do
   foo1 = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
   FooBar.should_receive(:create).with(id: foo1.id)
 end
end
```

but my test is failing with message

```
Failures:

   1) Foo create node in graph database on
      Failure/Error: FooBar.should_receive(:create).with(id: foo1.id)
      (<FooBar (class)>).create({:id=>18})
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay got around with problem

changed this

```
 it "create node in graph database" do
  foo1 = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
  FooBar.should_receive(:create).with(id: foo1.id)
end
```

to

```
 it "create node in graph database" do
  foo1 = FactoryGirl.build(:foo)
  FooBar.should_receive(:create).with(id: foo1.id)
  foo1.save
end
```

Comment: Why did that change anything? I refactored a test of mine exactly like you have it, but it still didn't work. Any ideas why and/or what RSpec is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with RSpec behind the scene, just simple logic. Before he changed it, the problem was `.create` was called before the `.should` test. After the change, `.build` is used to build the record, keep in mind at this point, the record is *not* created yet. Then he called `.save` to actually create the record. That's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but actually the above won't work. You can create a custom matcher to do it:

```
class EventualValueMatcher
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def ==(value)
    @block.call == value
  end
end

def eventual_value(&block)
  EventualValueMatcher.new(&block)
end
```

Then in your spec do:

```
it "create node in graph database" do
  foo1 = FactoryGirl.build(:foo)
  FooBar.should_receive(:create).with(eventual_value { { id: foo1.id } })
  foo1.save
end
```

This means that the mock will not evaluate the block until after the fact and it has actually been set.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, an updated version of Dan Draper solution to use a custom matcher with a block, would be like this:

```rb
# spec/support/eventual_value_matcher.rb

RSpec::Matchers.define :eventual_value do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual == expected.call
  end
end
```

And usage:

```rb
require "support/eventual_value_matcher" # or you can do a global require on the rails_helper.rb file

it "xxx" do
  foo1 = FactoryGirl.build(:foo)
  expect(FooBar).to receive(:create).with(eventual_value(proc { foo1.id }))
  foo.save!
end
```